# PagingList Sorting on Nested Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Say I have a two ViewModels: TasksViewModel.cs

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public DepartmentViewModel Department {get; set;}
}
```

and DeprtmentViewModel.cs

```
public class DeprtmentViewModel
{
    public String Title {get; set;}
}
```

I am creating a PagingList of TaskViewModel and Displaying it on a Table in a Razor Page.

PagingList Code in Controller:

```
PagingList.Create<TaskViewModel>(await _taskService.GetAll(taskFilterViewModel), _appSettings.PageSize, page,sortExpression,sortExpression);
```

I want to give the user the ability to sort the table according to the Task Title as well as Department Title.

I am able to implement sorting with respect to Task Title but I am unable to do this on Department Title (which is a nested property). **How can I sort the PagingList data on the nested property?**

In the table header of the razor Page:

```
<th>
    @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Title)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Department.Title)
</th>
```

Trying to sort data by clicking on Department Title give me an ArgumentException.

One way to overcome this is to use

```
@Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Department)
```

in the table header and implement `IComparable` with respect to Title for DepartmentViewModel. Is there any alternate, because, otherwise I have to Impelement IComparable for each nested property for which I want to implement sorting. Is there any other way to do this?